# How does os figure if a dll is already loaded in memory or how does os figure two dll are the same?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

In my comprehension, "dll/so" can be shared between programs(processes). for example when "libprint.so" is loaded in "main"(called main1) at first time, "libprint.so" is loaded from disk into memory, if we start another "main"(called main2), "libprint.so" will **not** loaded from disk but mapped from memory because "libprint.so" has been already loaded in memory once.

So i design an experiment:

main.cc --> main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
void printinfo();

int main() {
printinfo();
while(true) {
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
}
return 0;
}
```

print1.cc  -->  libprint1.so

```
#include <iostream>
void printinfo() {
std::cout << "Print One" << std::endl;
}
```

print2.cc  --> libprint2.so

```
#include <iostream>

void printinfo() {
std::cout << "Print Two" << std::endl;
}
```

```
mv libprint1.so libprint.so
./main
// output is: Print One
```

keep the main.exe running, and replace the libprint.dll with libprint2.dll, like

```
mv libprint2.so libprint.so
./main
// output is: Print Two
```

**why the output is "Print Two"? I expect it to be "Print One"**  the "libprint.so" is already loaded in memory, although i changed the content of "libprint.so", but the so's absolute path is the same as before, how does the operating system know the "new libprint.so" is different with before?

Thanks for @Michael Chourdakis, in windows environment, the libprint.dll **could not** be replaced when main.exe is running.

But the problem is still there in linux(libprint.so **could** be replaced in
linux), @user253751 says there must be some tricks that linux figure different "so", i want to know exactly what the tricks are, do i have to read the linux os source code ?

Comment: Could you actually replace libprint.dll while main was running?

Comment: Linux: same way it knows whether any two files are the same. Windows: I didn't think this was allowed?

Comment: Consider that the OS has to know whether two files are the same for many other reasons (e.g. if one process has one open for writing and another process has it open for reading)

Comment: This is not possible in Windows. You cannot replace a dll while it's in use.

Comment: What's that "mv" stuff? Is that some linux environement inside Windows?

Comment: I'm sorry.  you are right, the libprint.dll can not be replace in windows when main.exe is running @MichaelChourdakis  i'm using mingw("mv" is a linux command)

Comment: @riverlew a good thing to remember is that Windows developing doesn't resemble Linux in any way. Forget mingw and command line - focus on Visual Studio and GUI development.

Comment: You called the function only once; before an eternal loop of long term sleep. How did you get an output after move, while the program was running. Is that your original test code, or is there a typo while editing for the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to know exactly what the tricks are, do i have to read the linux os source code ?

What *actually* happens when you run `main` (which is presumably linked against `libprint.so`) (or at least "explainlikeimfive" version):

1. At the time the static link is performed (`g++ main.cpp ./libprint.so` or similar), the static linker records that (a) your program is dynamically linked and (b) that it requires `./libprint.so` to run. You can see this by looking at the output from `readelf -d main`. Another thing that is recorded is the dynamic loader (aka ELF interpreter), which you can see with `readelf -l main`.
2. When the Linux kernel starts the new process to run `main` in, it discovers  (by reading program headers) which ELF interpreter is to be used, `mmap`s that interpreter into memory, and transfers control to *it*. It is the job of the interpreter to `mmap` other libraries (including `libprint.so`), relocate them, arrange for proper symbol resolution, etc. etc.
3. The ELF interpreter uses `open` and `mmap` system calls to actually bring `libprint.so` into the process (this happens long before `main()` is called.
4. When any process calls `open("/some/path", ...)`, the OS (the Linux kernel) performs directory lookups to map the given path to a particular mounted filesystem and a unique inode on that that filesystem. Finally it (the OS) checks to see if that inode has *already* been opened by any other currently running process. If the file *is* open, then the kernel can *reuse* some of the in-kernel-memory structures it already allocated for that file <-- this is where the kernel discovers that it may not have to allocate new memory pages for `libprint.so` but can re-use the ones it already has.

When you do `mv libprint2.so libprint.so`, you *change* the inode number of `libprint.so`, so the kernel *knows* it's a totally different file. You can observe this by using `ls -li libprint.so` before and after `mv`.

Comment: thanks very much! the inode, that must be the answer!